# Can i use SCANF in a file and then make the stream go one position back?

Tags: c

I have a problem. I have two file tests. Let's suppose that 'file' both of the the file names.

I'm going to test on both of the files and one of them is like this:

```
1 2
```

and the other one is :

```
1 2

2                   
 4

3
    6
```

What I want to do is read the the file and save the numbers and test them. So if there's 2 numbers, it saves the 2 numbers and does a TEST in the numbers and closes the file but if there's 4 or 6 or 8 numbers in the file, I want to repeat my function BODY and only close my file until there's no numbers left. But there's one problem, I'm using the condition `IF(fscanf(fp, "%d", nova))` to check if there's anything left and if there are still numbers, I would have scanned a number that should be in the variable HEADS.

What I want to do is check if there's more numbers besides the first two and if there is, I want to start my function again and not skip a number because of the fscanf condition.

```
int Body(){

    int Head, Arms;
    int nova;
    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("file", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &Head);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &Arms);
    test(head, arms);
    if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &nova)==EOF) fclose(fp);
    else ....

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is for sure a way to do this by storing what you've read and not making the stream backtrack.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop instead of an extra `scanf()` to check if you've reached the end.

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &Head, &Arms) == 2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a seekable file, you can store the current position using `ftell` and then try to read the next number - if scanf was successful, `fseek` back to the position returned by `ftell` and call the function.

If you're just reading from a generic stream that might not be seekable, you can peek **one character** forward. I.e. you can use a space at the *end* of the `*scanf` format to eat the white space, and then try to read one more character using `getchar`/fgetc`- if this looks like a digit, you can use`ungetc` to push it back to the stream.

Comment: Thank you. I was also wondering, after I do push one position back to the stream, I would call the function again.  Is there any way to not open the file again since it's already opened in the right position ?

Comment: @Silverhelp naturally you should open it *outside* such a function and *pass the `FILE *` as an argument*.